# What is the difference between a favorite question and a followed question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

If I favour a question, does that mean I'm following it? And vice versa? What's the difference?

Comment: Favorite question has a specific meaning in SE software - see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/favorites/info) for links to some basic information. I am not sure whether *following* a question has precisely defined meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't such a thing as "a followed question" in Stack Exchange interface, so the "favorite questions" serve this role. Marking a question as  a favorite allows you to:

1. Look it up later in your list of favorites (on your profile page), which can be sorted in various ways.
2. Get a pseudo-notification of activity in those questions: it does not appear in your inbox, but is shown as a red badge with a number on the favorites tab in your profile.
3. Search  such questions in the future  by using `infavorites:mine` search operator.

See also: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at an icon that is the result of a Chrome add-on. That's what threw me.